# Problem working with project partner I picked

Tags: team, project-management, teamleader

Soon I'm going to turn 16 and in school, I have to start work on a major project which will be very valuable for my end-year certificate.

A few weeks back I engaged with a friendly student who just joined my class from China. She doesn't speak my home language very well but I thought it would be interesting to do this project in English. In addition, she didn't have a partner yet and from the looks of it, it was very unlikely she would get one (many students find her odd). But I was open and we met up. Now we are both partners for this project.

Before this, I already had an idea for my project and I wanted to do it in IT. I am very advanced compared to my classmates in this matter, because I already started coding at the age of 10 and attended government-funded events. She didn't have any knowledge of this subject. Of course, it was my error to pick her as a partner, because she also doesn't have a lot of experience at holding presentations but from my impression, she was ready to learn a lot.

Of course, now you could ask yourself: "So what's the problem?". Well, now one month into the future she is very frustrating for me and hard to understand. In addition, I find she overreacts when I try to give feedback. Just now she messaged me that I was a little harsh but "this time" she will forgive me. Actually, she did a small mistake and added the wrong title of our paper to the teacher. But I understood that maybe for her I was a little too frustrated so I apologized minutes later. So I can't really relate to why she messages this to me 4 hours later.

I actually also don't really want to work with her anymore and want to try to work on my own, because I think she would distract a lot and wouldn't bring a lot of positive outcomes. Furthermore, I could only change my partner at this stage through talking to her and to my professional teacher which could be difficult.

How should I handle this problem?

Comment: hi and welcome. Your question lacks objective goal: what would you like to happen? Also: i edited your question fro clarity of reading and the title to be more descriptive, feel free to roll back as necessary

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about the workplace.

Comment: This might be a better fit for [Interpersonal Skills StackExchange](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Comment: Hey Ryan, totally understand that. I tried to delete it but it said that people invested time in this which I totally respect. However, I do not feel affiliated with this post anymore. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Take a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/165261 for more information about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kevin brought up the positive aspects of being involved with this project and person, so I'm going to cover the more pragmatic ones. These are some lessons that you wish to take to heart, or at least be aware of.

You seem like a bright kid (anyone who starts programming at 10 probably is), and you'll find yourself running into this situations like these more and more as you advance through your education. Situations where you'll feel that you'd be better off doing the whole project by yourself, even if it means pulling an all-nighter.

This is for a number of reasons, but mainly because the bottleneck in a group is always going to be the lowest common denominator. The efforts of the group are going to be hobbled by the least talented/intelligent/motivated/hard-working member. Always.

In your particular situation, you are very passionate about programming, while your partner, no matter how intelligent otherwise, doesn't have your knowledge, or simply isn't.

Your ambitions and passions are not shared, and thus she isn't contributing the same amount of effort, and doesn't understand the challenges and priorities the same way you do. You'll find plenty of examples of people facing these problems even in their 40's right here, on this website.

Another thing you failed to anticipate, and which you'll run into over and over again over your life, is how critical communication is in a group. You're encountering difficulties which should be a major red flag in any project you're ever going to be involved in, either in school, or in the workplace.

Any time people from multiple backgrounds, who may not share a language, the same understanding of a language, or simply speak the same language with vastly different accents, you will encounter difficulties. In these situations you'll find that you have to slow your pace, and emphasize communication above all else, such that costly misunderstandings don't occur.

In retrospect, it probably seems pretty obvious that someone who just moved to a foreign country may have some misgivings about presenting in front of a bunch of people who are very foreign to her, in a language which she doesn't speak very well.

Last but not least, you'll find that people of different cultural background are not simply different because they speak a different language. They have a different understanding of what's acceptable in polite society, what sort of criticism can be rendered, what sort of topics are up for discussion, who should lead a group based on which qualifications, and many other issues besides.

In the future you're going to have to probe the depths of those cultural differences more carefully, such that conflict does not arise. This *also* slows development down.

If you have the option to go back to your teacher and ask to work on the project by yourself, you can do so, and offer the communication barrier as a reason for why you guys can't get move forward as a team. However, you should probably discuss the issue with her first, and tell her that you think the two of you should work separately. This way, she can communicate her own opinions, and either offer a solution, or agree that you should approach the teacher.

Here's how you could trigger this conversation:

> Hey, X. After working together for a few days, I think you're not really very excited about this programming task as I am, and I was wondering if maybe you wanted to work on something else. We could talk to the teacher, and tell her that we've decided to work on different projects. Would you mind doing so?

You can massage this message as needed, of course. And remember, if you have misgivings about this situation, she probably does as well, with the added complexity of not knowing how the system works, or what's socially acceptable. Maybe this will come as a relief for her, as much as for you.

Comment: One minor aspect that I would phrase differently: Instead of "I think you're not really very exited about this programming task" you could say "we seem to have different ideas on how to approach this project" or something similar which sounds less judgemental. Yet, personally, I would advise to continue the project together in order to improve team work and communication skills.

Answer (score 2):

**I'm going to give you an answer you might not expect: Don't Worry About Success**

You're looking at all the downsides of the situation.  Why not look at the positives?

- You're 16.  If you fail this project, so what?  I'd argue that
  failure might be the *better* outcome, because you'll probably learn
  more applicable lessons for the future from it.
- You're working with someone with a different skill set.  This is
  awesome!  You keep thinking, "Man, she sucks at IT", but instead,
  think: "Man, we can do a better project because she can handle skills
  that I wouldn't be able to do."  Is she good at music?  Program a
  random song generator.  Is she good at art?  Program an
  artistic-centered game.  Is she good at athletics?  Program a fitness
  app.
- You're working with someone that operates in a different thought
  process than you.  Awesome!  Because, when you start your career,
  you'll be doing that a lot.  Instead of lamenting that she's not
  just-like-you, try to figure out how her mind works.  Step outside
  your usual pattern, figure out different ways of communicating, etc.
- You're working with someone that is criticizing you.  Excellent!  I
  mean, yeah, it sucks, but I'll tell you this: the faster you can
  improve as a person, the better you'll do at life.  Criticism is one
  of the best ways - when someone criticizes you *and you can honestly
  admit there's some truth to the criticism*, work on improving.

**In short: the more you focus on "Was this particular project a success" instead of "Did I improve because of this project", the less long-term good you'll find this project gives you.**

Comment: Three things: **1)** Failure is rarely the _better_ outcome. Lessons are better learned without crashing and burning. **2)** Most times you absolutely have to worry about success, because the project in question can make/break your career, or a grade that you need, even if your partner doesn't. Successful people worry about success, or at least the perception of success. **3)** Criticism is only valuable if it is honest, and actionable. Being criticized for speaking the truth because the other person does not wish their actions questioned is not criticism you should do any soul-searching over.

Comment: We do not know the criteria that will be used in grading the project. Teamwork have a significant weight. The OP needs to find out how a solo project will be graded before burning bridges with the OP's current partner.